# How to detect real size of svg path in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I'm trying to get real "path" size, using `getBoundingClientRect` function for that, but in FireFox I get different results

In Google Chrome all is well:

```
1. 100px x 100px
2. 100px x 100px
```

But in FireFox:

```
1. 104px x 104px
2. 100px x 100px
```

Why `stroke-width="1"` added 4px? How to get real size without empty spaces in FF?

[image]

```html
<div>With stroke-width="1"</div>
<svg width="110" height="110">
  <path stroke-width="1" d="M0 0 L 100 0 L100 100 L 0 100 Z" fill="black" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>
<br>
<br>
<div>With stroke-width="0"</div>
<svg width="110" height="110">
  <path stroke-width="0" d="M0 0 L 100 0 L100 100 L 0 100 Z" fill="black" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>
```

P.S.
I'm triyng to add "line with text" to this path. I get path position+size with `getBoundingClientRect` function, create new div in those coordinates.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Chrome is wrong, your path is not 100 x 100. The stroke sticks out 2 pixels from each edge making it 104 x 104.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm triyng to add "line with text" to this path. I get path position+size with `getBoundingClientRect` function, create new div in this coordinates. Result: http://s1.micp.ru/i6QC3.png

Comment: Your problem is you're creating a path that's 104 pixels wide/high and then clipping it to 100 pixels with the container <svg> element. You measure the path rather than the container and then try to position the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made solution for FF. Simple but it works.

```
last_current.attr('stroke-width',0); // FireFox fix!
let c_pos = last_current[0].getBoundingClientRect();
last_current.attr('stroke-width', 1); // FireFox fix!
```